# Do hired thugs only attack once?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I admit it, I killed a "battle-born" in Whiterun and now have a bounty. That is fine with me.  What I want to know is after the first attack of hired thugs, can I expect more attacks?

If so, will I have to deal with them the whole game?

Comment: there won't be thugs for you if you killed, only if you stole something.

Answer (score 3):

I did not kill anyone but I did pickpocket a <s>cureor</s> <s>curior</s> <s>currror</s> <s>"Letter Carrying Person"</s> Courier (thanks Magicmaster) the start of the game. I had thugs sent after me with instructions from the guy I stole from, but I was never bothered again after I killed them once.

Comment: Courier :) 1234

Answer (score 1):

I have had multiple thugs sent to me from the same shopkeeper.  I'm not sure if it was due to me stealing multiple items or the fact that for the first group of thugs, I was in the mage academy and the wizards there took care of them without me having to lift a hand.